# UV Unwrap onto cylinder

Tags: uv

This has to be unwrapping 101 level 0 beginner noob
But i cant get my head around it - can build a scene, can't unwrap a bottle

Here's the real thing
[image]

Heres a 3d version i quickly made with the design all messed up and i cant get it to simply wrap around the bottle and join so the name connects
[image]

Heres the edit mode
[image]

heres the image im trying to mockup onto it
[image]

.blend file
https://we.tl/t-pGYMQN4RnB

Can someone please help with this simple noobish hurdle?

ta

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Select the cylinder faces, unwrap with the *Cylinder Projection* mode, in the *Operator* box activate *Align to Object* and *Scale to Bounds*:

[image]

It works:

[image]

Comment: Just like that - i knew it was one or two buttons away. Thank you so much moonboots

Answer (score 2):

One way is:

1. Add a vertical seam where you want to place the middle of *name*.
2. Then unwrap the area where you want to apply the texture.
3. Scale the uv map so that the vertical borders of the map and of the texture match. If you only scale along the x axis the image on the cylinder will appear vertically squeezed. If you scale along both the x and y axis you will not be able to vertically cover the whole cylinder. Thus, with your setting the image will be repeated until the cylinder is covered. Instead, if you want only one copy of the texture at the bottom of the cylinder: first translate the uv map along the y axis so that the bottom borders of the texture and the uv map match; then, on the image node in node editor, change Repeat into Extended.