# How do I UV unwrap this coffee label? Without addons preferably

Tags: uv

How do I UV unwrap this coffee label? Without addons preferably without joining issues at base.

[image]

Comment: if you want a square unwrap, try the Follow Active Quads option

Comment: Or try _Cylinder Projection_ and _Direction > Align to Object_.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56748/how-to-unwrap-a-drink-can/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74041/how-to-perfectly-align-uv-coordinates-automatically https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78358/how-to-straighten-curved-uvs-into-straight-belt/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/267513/uv-unwrap-onto-cylinder https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/69267/uv-unwrapping-a-hollow-cylinder-sequentially https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39792/how-can-i-apply-textures-without-them-stretching/

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Thanks very much your links helped me.

Comment: @moonboots Thanks very much

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Thanks very much